# Problema al concatenar un switch en echo de PHP

Tags: php, webservice, aplicación-web

Estoy intentando seleccionar productos especificos segun una query hacia una base de datos.
El problema surgue al momento de usar un SWITCH dentro de un echo.
Al parecer es un problema de concatenacion, pero no logro resultado

```php
echo ('<div class="d-flex align-items-center"><a class="btn '.
      switch(strtoupper($status)) {
           case 'ENTREGADO':
               echo "text-success";
               break;
           case 'CANCELADO':
               echo "text-light";
               break;
           case 'PENDIENTE':
               echo "text-badDayForPHP";
               break; 
      }.'" href="javascript:void(0);">'.strtoupper($row["status"]).'</a>');
```

Que estoy haciendo mal?

var_dump: syntax error, unexpected 'switch' (T_SWITCH)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo puedes concatenar variables o valores, tu estás concatenando un `string` con la sintaxis del propio lenguaje, cosa que no es posible.

Como solución puedes crear una variable y asignar su contenido en el switch.

```
<?php

$status = 'ENTREGADO';
$class = "";
switch(strtoupper($status)) {
           case 'ENTREGADO':
               $class = "text-success";
               break;
           case 'CANCELADO':
               $class = "text-light";
               break;
           case 'PENDIENTE':
               $class = "text-badDayForPHP";
               break; 
}
echo ('<div class="d-flex align-items-center"><a class="btn '. $class .'" href="javascript:void(0);">'.strtoupper($row["status"]).'</a>');
```